# Creating DataFrames from cell ranges to create an output

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


 data_location = ""
os.chdir(data_location)

df1 = pd.read_excel('Calculation - (Vodafone) July 22.xlsx', sheet_name='PPD Summary', 
index_col=False)
df2 = df1.iat[3, 5]
df3 = df1.iat[4, 5]
df4 = '9999305'
df5 = df1.iat[3, 1]
df6 = df1.iat[4, 1]
df7 = df1.iat[3, 6]
df8 = df1.iat[4, 6]

print(df4, df5, df2, df7)
print(df4, df6, df3, df8)
```

Running this script will return me the following which I want to output to a csv:

```
9999305 0.007018639425878576 GB GBP
9999305 0.006709984038878434 IE EUR
```

The cells which contain the information I need are in B5:B6, F5:F6 & G5:G6. I have tried using openpyxl to get the cell ranges, however I am struggling to present and output these in a way so that csv that is outputted like the above.

Comment: Hi there, can you please a short sample of your excel file?  That will really help in creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 

Could you also please clarify what your desired output is?  If you want a CSV of that output you posted you are very close, just replace those spaces with commas and you've got a CSV.

Comment: It sounds like you want to filter some rows and columns. Do they columns have titles? And what about the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame([[df4, df5, df2, df7],
                       [df4, df6, df3, df8]])
result.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

`'filename.csv'` will contain:

```
9999305,0.007018639425878576,GB,GBP
9999305,0.006709984038878434,IE,EUR
```

---

If you want just to print them in a comma-separated-format:

```py
print(df4, df5, df2, df7, sep=',')
print(df4, df6, df3, df8, sep=',')
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Fokow. This works and is very helpful :) . Is there a way I can put cell ranges B5:B6, G5:G6 & F5:F6 into individual data frames so that is simpler, instead of using .iat?

Comment: Well, you would still need to select the values somehow (why don't you like selecting with `iat` ?)

Comment: With this file I'm only pulling data from B5:B6 etc. I have bigger files where the range will be substantially bigger from B5:B185. If I could make a DataFrame where i'm stating the range instead of by column and row it would be much easier

Comment: @JamesUpson this is a candidate for another question. If you ask it, please try to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): a small example input (what you have) and output (what you'd like to get)